# How to use an alias or function in zsh to check for a socket and run the appropriate command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, zsh, zeus

I have an interesting problem when using [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) with Rails. My shell script writing is lacking to say the least.

Ok, so zeus boots a rails app in under a second and makes tests etc. much faster. However, you must append `zeus` before any rails command. Example, `zeus generate controller` or `zeus rake db:migrate`. I would rather keep the regular rails commands while running zeus. Example, `rails generate controller` or `rake db:migrate`.

I have these 3 commands aliased

`alias rails='zeus'`

`alias rspec='zeus rspec'`

`alias rake='zeus rake'`

However, if zeus is not running, I get this error

```
error: Can't connect to master. Run zeus start first.
```

So the **problem I'm trying to solve** is I would like to use the same rails commands **whether zeus is running or not**

Now when I run `zeus start` it seems that `zeus.sock` is present. So I guess I could check for the presence of `zeus.sock` in a function and then set up the alias accordingly. Im just not sure the best way to do this. I know that `-S`  is true if file exists and is a socket. something like

```
if [ -S zeus.sock ]; then 
  # not sure where to go from here
```

Anybody have a suggestion on the best way to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Seems relevant to your problem, its someones solution for the same problem you have. https://github.com/jasoncodes/dotfiles/blob/master/shell/aliases/rails.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function, perhaps like this:

```
zrail() {
    if [ -S zeus.sock ]; then
        zeus $*
    else
        rails $*
    fi
}
```

Then you call it like:

```
zrail generate controller
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was close. After some more digging, I found I was missing `command rails "$@"` in the else clause. This allowed me to use rails in the function name, which is what I really wanted. Thanks